# Zend Studio or Eclipse PDT project managment

Tags: eclipse-pdt, zend-studio

After years of using notepad++ for web development I've decided to start using some IDE. I've tried both: Zend Studio and Eclipse PDT. It appears they are pretty much similar.

When working on multiple projects I used to make "sessions" in notepad++ to keep each project files opened in editor. How do I achieve that in Zend Studio or Eclipse PDT? I mean when switching the project, I want one set of files to be closed in editor and another one to be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Try Aptana studio, use the plugin manager to add PDT and other dev' support. for me it was the best solution.
(It's eclipse, but very featured)

Comment: I have tried. Same thing as with Zend Studio or Eclipse PDT - I don't see a way to manage sets of files (tabs) for each project.